# Update 2 pivot tables on single worksheet

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I'm having an issue I've run into a wall with. I have 2 pivot tables on a single worksheet that both use the same data source, but provide different 'views' of the data. However, one table is linked to a PivotChart and both are connected to a few slicers. When I remove one of the tables (and associated coding) the macro works fine, but if I add another pivot table back in, I receieve "run-time error '5'". I can't figure out how to resolve this :(

Current macro:

```
Sub UpdatePivs()

    Dim SrcData As String
    Dim SourceRows As Long

    SourceRows = Worksheets("Source Data").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    SrcData = "'Source Data'"!A2:AZ" & SourceRows

    Worksheets("Assigned").PivotTables("AssignedTable").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)
    Worksheets("Assigned").PivotTables("AssignedTable").RefreshTable

    Worksheets("Assigned").PivotTables("TBDTable").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)
    Worksheets("Assigned").PivotTables("TBDTable").RefreshTable
```

I've seen some posts suggesting to convert the source to a table, however, I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require that.

Any help would be appreciated :) I also apologize for any formatting weirdness. On mobile currently

EDIT: I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to avoid turning the source data into a Table? Because that solves the problem perfectly. Furthermore, if both PivotTables point at the same table, then they both share the same PivotCache, meaning if you refresh one, you refresh both.

Comment: Just my own fear of change I guess, haha. I'll give this a test run!

Comment: Cool. There are many, many compelling reasons to embrace Tables. They open the door to a good many new things in Excel, plus can radically simplify and de-risk spreadsheets.

Comment: So I was finally able to test things out! For some reason I couldn't get the macro to work properly, even when using a table (but I'll still be delving into tables, since I've seen so much praise for them).

Comment: However, it seems the issue was with the slicers being connected to both pivot tables (at least in the workbook I was using). So the method I had to use was a bit different. I'll post as an answer just in case anyone else runs into this problem. Thank you again for your insight and assistance with this!

Answer (score 0):

After testing out a few things with the macro above, it worked perfectly when the slicers weren't connected to one of the pivot tables. Therefore, I tried testing out a few things that would accomplish the following:

1) Disconnect the slicers from the 2nd table
2) Update the source data for both tables
3) Refresh the pivot tables
4) Connect the slicers back to the 2nd table

I ended up with the coding below, which was able to get me past all the issues I kept hitting by removing the slicer connections so the data could update, kept the pivot cache between the 2 tables the same, so that the slicers could reconnect & finally updated the table source data and reconnect the slicers.

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to accomplish all this, but I am still pretty new to all of this :)

```
'Refresh tables
    Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("TBDvAssign").RefreshTable
    Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView").RefreshTable

'Remove slices from pivot table 2
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable _(Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Region").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Role").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Sponsor").PivotTables.RemovePivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))

'Update pivot cache of pivot table 1 & refresh
    Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("TBDvAssign").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)
    Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("TBDvAssign").RefreshTable

'Update pivot cache of pivot table 2 to be the same as pivot table 1 & update
    Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("Full").ChangePivotCache ("TBDvAssign")
    Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("Full").RefreshTable

'Assign slicers back to pivot table 2
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").PivotTables.AddPivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Project").PivotTables.AddPivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Region").PivotTables.AddPivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Role").PivotTables.AddPivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Sponsor").PivotTables.AddPivotTable (Worksheets("TBD v. Assigned").PivotTables("FullView"))
```